# how to figure out correct headers of an excel file programmatically while reading it from pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I have a list of excel files (.xlsx,.xls), I'm trying to get headers of each of these files after loaded.

Here I have taken a one excel file and loaded into pandas as.

```
pd.read_excel("sample.xlsx")
```

output is:

[image]

Here we would like to get an header information as per our requirement, here in the attached image  the required headers are existed at index 8 as you can see in red color coded.

```
pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx',skiprows=9)
```

as we know now we have a correct header at 8 i can go back and specify in read_excel as skip_rows at 8 so that it reads from this index and headers will be appeared as.

[image]

How to handle this type of cases programmatically among a list of excel files where we don't know where the header is existed? in this case we have known that header is at 8. but what if we don't know this in other files.

Sample file can be downloaded for your ref:
https://github.com/myamullaciencia/pg_diploma_ai_ml_uohyd/blob/main/sample_file.xlsx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.read_excel('sample_file.xlsx')

#test all rows if previous row is only NaNs
m1 = df.shift(fill_value=0).isna().all(axis=1)
#test all rows if no NaNs
m2 = df.notna().all(axis=1)
#chain together and filter all next rows after first match
df = df[(m1 & m2).cummax()]

#set first row to columns names
df = df.set_axis(df.iloc[0].rename(None), axis=1).iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)

print (df)
   LN  FN          SSN        DOB        DOH Gender  Comp_2011 Comp_2010  \
0  Ax  Bx  000-00-0000   8/3/1800   1/1/1800   Male  384025.56    396317   
1  Er  Ds  000-00-0000   5/7/1800   7/1/1800   Male  382263.86    392474   
2  Po  Ch  000-00-0000   9/9/1800   1/1/1800   Male  406799.34    395677   
3  Rt  Da  000-00-0000  6/24/1800   7/1/1800   Male  395767.12    424093   
4  Yh  St  000-00-0000  3/15/1800   7/1/1800   Male  376936.58    373754   
5  Ws  Ra  000-00-0000  6/12/1800  7/10/1800   Male  425720.06    420927   

  Comp_2009 Allocation Group                  NRD  
0    360000             0.05  2022-09-01 00:00:00  
1    360000             0.05  2015-06-01 00:00:00  
2    360000             0.05  2013-01-01 00:00:00  
3    360000             0.05  2020-07-01 00:00:00  
4    360000                0  2013-01-01 00:00:00  
5    306960                0  2034-07-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: It seems to be working, but i have about 4K files not sure what to keep in here: df[df.iloc[:, 0].eq('LN').cummax()]. for this case you have kept 'LN'

Comment: @myamulla_ciencia - how are distinguish if row in data is column?

Comment: Let us take a case for this : Row should be filed in with some value it not be NaN nor Unnamed etc etc kind of condition. In this case we have a 11 columns at an index 8 all of these 11 columns filled in with a some value, so consider it as a Column header.

Comment: @myamulla_ciencia - answer was edited.

Comment: I'm getting this error on some files: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: @myamulla_ciencia - it means there not exist row with only missing values and next row with no missing values, can you check?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243576/discussion-between-myamulla-ciencia-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
df = pd.read_excel('sample_file.xlsx', header = None)
d = df[df[5] == 'Gender'].index[0]
ndf = df[d+1:]
ndf.columns = df.loc[d].values
ndf.reset_index(drop = True)
```

Output:

Please note that the idea is that the `Gender` is always in the headers.

[image]

Based on your comment, you can use the following condition:

```
df[df.notna().sum(axis = 1)==11].index[0]
```

Comment: Yeah. this should be OK. but in my case not sure Gender is always present in the dataframe.